# Customizing Excel UI/Ribbon with VS2017?

Tags: vba, vb.net, visual-studio-2017, customization, ribbon

Currently I have extended Excel with:

(1) VBA code.
(2) XML code using "Custum UI Editor for Microsoft Office" in which I customize the Ribbon.

I am also working with Visual Studio Community 2017, where I have some project coded in VB.NET. However, I am not at all familiar with C# or other languages.

My customizations in Exccel include dynamic menus as well as added build-in groups to custom tabs, so I don’t think I can use the "Ribbon designer".

I have been testing a little with Visual Studio for customizing the Ribbon of Excel, but the VBA code gives me problems with referencing to e.g. current selections of cells in Excel:

```
Private Sub FormatTusindtals0(control As IRibbonControl)
    Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
End Sub
```

And now I wonder whether Visual Studio is a better tool than the "Custum UI Editor for Microsoft Office" for customizing the Ribbon?

Any input to whether VS2017 is a better choice than "Custum UI Editor for Microsoft Office" – and how to get all my VBA Subs and Functions to work in VS2017 is very appreciated!

THANKS!

Comment: Yes, the brilliant UI Editor is "RibbonXML Editor" - http://novikov.gq/products/ribbonxmleditor/ ,I'm working with it since 2007 version of MS, unfortunately, it presented only in RUS version (and absolutely free), you can download it from here: http://novikov.gq/counter_fd/counter_fd.php?file=ribbonxmleditor